# Radio button indicators not showing up

Tags: python, glade, pygobject

I am new to GUI development and have recently started developing a simple app on Ubuntu by designing the UI with glade and writing the code in python using PyGObject. I have done decently so far until I ran into a mysterious issue.

The indicators of radio buttons on a child window are not showing up. I have been able to toggle them and retrieve which button is active but the indicators themselves do not show up. I have compared the Properties of these buttons with two other radio buttons that I have put up on the main window (look and work as expected) but do not see any difference.

Could someone suggest a way to fix this? I am not sure what all information is required but here are a few images for starters.

[Screenshot from glade](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsoGe.png)

[General Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdNQe.png)

[Common Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fqTS.png)

[Screenshot from the executable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yf3l9.png)

Edit: Code which brings up the generate logs window

```
def on_generate_logs_activate(self, widget):

    #Setup generate logs window
    self.builder.add_from_file("myprogram6.glade")
    self.generate_logs_window = self.builder.get_object("generate_logs_window")
    self.generate_logs_window.show_all()
    self.all_records = self.builder.get_object("all_records") #Radio1
    self.specific_record = self.builder.get_object("specific_record") #Radio2
    self.dialog_record_combo = self.builder.get_object("dialog_record_combo")
    self.generate = self.builder.get_object("generate")
    self.dialog_close = self.builder.get_object("dialog_close")
    self.record_set1 = self.builder.get_object("liststore1")
    self.dialog_record_combo.set_sensitive(False)

    #Setup combotext
    self.dialog_record_combo.set_entry_text_column(1)
    records = self.get_unprocessed_records()
    for record in records:
        record=record.split('.')
        self.record_set1.append([record[0]])

    #Radios
    self.all_records.connect("toggled", self.on_all_records_toggled)
    self.specific_record.connect("toggled", self.on_specific_record_toggled)

    #Generate button
    self.generate.connect("clicked", self.on_generate_clicked)

    #Close button
    self.dialog_close.connect("clicked", self.on_dialog_close_clicked)
```

Please let me know if you would like me to add more information.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you didn't call window.show_all(). Again, I'm guessing because you didn't post your code, so it's impossible to know.

Comment: I did call window.show_all(). I updated the question with the code. Please take a look

Answer (score 0):

Look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxqZ_2fz-ZI
My speculation: you did not structure correctly your application.
Look at video 4 and 5 and you will understand how to structure.
a) python file creation with import at the top. so call it application.py and include

```
import gi
#
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk, Gdk as gdk, GLib, GObject as gobject

gobject.threads_init()
import string  # not used for now
import os  # not used for now
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
import threading..
```

b) class GUI (called "foo" in the video) hereunder called GUIclass
c) several def linked to the glade file within that class
d) **init** with import of the glade file
e) main

see few extracts below. look at few applications done with glade / pygtk on github.

```
class GUIclass:
    #
def exit_action(self, widget, data=None):
 self.exitdialog.show()

def exit_confirmed(self, widget, data=None):

 self.exitdialog.hide()

 game_not_cancelled = False
 ...
 gtk.main_quit()
 return True

def exit_aborted(self, widget, data=None):
    self.exitdialog.hide()

def watch_stop_yes(self, widget, data=None):


#
def deactivate_event_mode(self, widget, data=None):
   ...
def __init__(self):
    ...
    number_of_period = 2
    watch_stop_default = True
    add_time_seconds = 0
    #

    # define all relations between labels and entries and combobox and spinbutton and python variables
    builder = gtk.Builder()

    builder.add_from_file("/home/family/glade/scoreboard_uwr_180815.glade")
    #
    # load all windows
    self.controlwindow = builder.get_object("scoreboard_control_window")
    self.viewwindow = builder.get_object("scoreboard_view_window")
    self.logdialog = builder.get_object("scoreboard_log_dialog")
    self.logoffdialog = builder.get_object("scoreboard_logoff_confirm")
    self.logcanceldialog = builder.get_object("scoreboard_logcancel_confirm")
    self.resetdialog = builder.get_object("scoreboard_resetconfirm")
    self.exitdialog = builder.get_object("scoreboard_exitconfirm")
    #
    # declaration of all data from the "scoreboard_control_window"
    self.spinbutton_points_team_left = builder.get_object("spinbutton_points_team_left")
    self.spinbutton_points_team_right = builder.get_object("spinbutton_points_team_right")
    self.spinbutton_timeout_left = builder.get_object("spinbutton_timeout_left")
    self.spinbutton_timeout_right = builder.get_object("spinbutton_timeout_right")
    self.spinbutton_period_time = builder.get_object("spinbutton_period_time")
    self.spinbutton_period = builder.get_object("spinbutton_period")
    self.spinbutton_break_time = builder.get_object("spinbutton_break_time")
    self.spinbutton_penalty_duration = builder.get_object("spinbutton_penalty_duration")
    self.spinbutton_timeout = builder.get_object("spinbutton_timeout")
    self.spinbutton_time_penalty = builder.get_object("spinbutton_time_penalty")
    self.spinbutton_add_time = builder.get_object("spinbutton_add_time")
    self.spinbutton_warning_timepenalty = builder.get_object("spinbutton_warning_timepenalty")
    self.spinbutton_warning_break_timeout = builder.get_object("spinbutton_warning_break_timeout")
    #
    self.togglebutton_start_stop_game = builder.get_object("togglebutton_start_stop_game")
    #        self.comboboxtext_watch_stop = builder.get_object("comboboxtext_watch_stop")
    self.entry_tournament_name = builder.get_object("entry_tournament_name")
    self.entry_tournament_contact = builder.get_object("entry_tournament_contact")
    self.entry_team_blue_name = builder.get_object("entry_team_blue_name")
    self.entry_team_white_name = builder.get_object("entry_team_white_name")
    self.entry_name_penalty_player_1_left = builder.get_object("entry_name_penalty_player_1_left")
    self.entry_name_penalty_player_2_left = builder.get_object("entry_name_penalty_player_2_left")
    self.entry_name_penalty_player_3_left = builder.get_object("entry_name_penalty_player_3_left")
    self.entry_name_penalty_player_1_right = builder.get_object("entry_name_penalty_player_1_right")
    self.entry_name_penalty_player_2_right = builder.get_object("entry_name_penalty_player_2_right")
    self.entry_name_penalty_player_3_right = builder.get_object("entry_name_penalty_player_3_right")
    # define here further entries
    #
    self.label_control_current_time = builder.get_object("label_control_current_time")
    self.eventbox_control_left = builder.get_object("eventbox_control_left")
    #        self.eventbox_blue_team = builder.get_object("eventbox_blue_team")
    self.label_control_team_name_left = builder.get_object("label_control_team_name_left")
    self.eventbox_control_right = builder.get_object("eventbox_control_right")
    self.label_control_team_name_right = builder.get_object("label_control_team_name_right")
    self.label_control_tournament_name = builder.get_object("label_control_tournament_name")
    self.label_control_tournament_contact = builder.get_object("label_control_tournament_contact")
    self.spinbutton_minutes_time_correction = builder.get_object("spinbutton_minutes_time_correction")
    self.spinbutton_seconds_time_correction = builder.get_object("spinbutton_seconds_time_correction")
    #        self.label_special_time_sequence = builder.get_object("label_special_time_sequence")
    #
    self.label_control_time_penalty_player_1_left = builder.get_object("label_control_time_penalty_player_1_left")
    self.label_control_time_penalty_player_2_left = builder.get_object("label_control_time_penalty_player_2_left")
    self.label_control_time_penalty_player_3_left = builder.get_object("label_control_time_penalty_player_3_left")
    self.label_control_time_penalty_player_1_right = builder.get_object("label_control_time_penalty_player_1_right")
    self.label_control_time_penalty_player_2_right = builder.get_object("label_control_time_penalty_player_2_right")
    self.label_control_time_penalty_player_3_right = builder.get_object("label_control_time_penalty_player_3_right")
    #
    #        self.label_timeout = builder.get_object("label_timeout")
    #        self.label_break = builder.get_object("label_break")
    #        self.label_penalty = builder.get_object("label_penalty")
    #
    self.spinbutton_points_team_left = builder.get_object("spinbutton_points_team_left")
    self.spinbutton_points_team_right = builder.get_object("spinbutton_points_team_right")
    self.eventbox_control_points_team_left = builder.get_object("eventbox_control_points_team_left")
    self.eventbox_control_points_team_right = builder.get_object("eventbox_control_points_team_right")
    self.label_control_points_team_left = builder.get_object("label_control_points_team_left")
    self.label_control_points_team_right = builder.get_object("label_control_points_team_right")
    self.label_control_special_time_sequence = builder.get_object("label_control_special_time_sequence")
    self.eventbox_control_team_name_left = builder.get_object("eventbox_control_team_name_left")
    self.eventbox_control_team_name_right = builder.get_object("eventbox_control_team_name_right")
    #
    # declaration of all data from the view window
    self.eventbox_view_team_color_left = builder.get_object("eventbox_view_team_color_left")
    self.eventbox_view_team_color_right = builder.get_object("eventbox_view_team_color_right")
    self.eventbox_view_points_team_left = builder.get_object("eventbox_view_points_team_left")
    self.eventbox_view_points_team_right = builder.get_object("eventbox_view_points_team_right")
    self.label_view_period = builder.get_object("label_view_period")
    self.label_view_current_time = builder.get_object("label_view_current_time")
    self.label_view_points_team_left = builder.get_object("label_view_points_team_left")
    self.label_view_timeout_left = builder.get_object("label_view_timeout_left")
    self.label_view_timeout_right = builder.get_object("label_view_timeout_right")
    self.label_view_points_team_right = builder.get_object("label_view_points_team_right")
    self.eventbox_view_team_color_left = builder.get_object("eventbox_view_team_color_left")
    self.eventbox_view_team_color_right = builder.get_object("eventbox_view_team_color_right")

    self.label_view_team_name_left = builder.get_object("label_view_team_name_left")
    self.label_view_team_name_right = builder.get_object("label_view_team_name_right")
    self.eventbox_view_team_name_left = builder.get_object("eventbox_view_team_name_left")
    self.eventbox_view_team_name_right = builder.get_object("eventbox_view_team_name_right")

    self.label_view_tournament_name = builder.get_object("label_view_tournament_name")
    self.label_view_tournament_contact = builder.get_object("label_view_tournament_contact")
    self.label_view_specific_timesequence = builder.get_object("label_view_specific_timesequence")
    self.label_view_status_specific_timesequence = builder.get_object("label_view_status_specific_timesequence")
    self.label_view_special_time_sequence = builder.get_object("label_view_special_time_sequence")
    self.label_view_time_penalty_player_1_left = builder.get_object("label_view_time_penalty_player_1_left")
    self.label_view_time_penalty_player_2_left = builder.get_object("label_view_time_penalty_player_2_left")
    self.label_view_time_penalty_player_3_left = builder.get_object("label_view_time_penalty_player_3_left")
    self.label_view_time_penalty_player_1_right = builder.get_object("label_view_time_penalty_player_1_right")
    self.label_view_time_penalty_player_2_right = builder.get_object("label_view_time_penalty_player_2_right")
    self.label_view_time_penalty_player_3_right = builder.get_object("label_view_time_penalty_player_3_right")
    #
    self.label_view_name_penalty_player_1_left = builder.get_object("label_view_name_penalty_player_1_left")
    self.label_view_name_penalty_player_2_left = builder.get_object("label_view_name_penalty_player_2_left")
    self.label_view_name_penalty_player_3_left = builder.get_object("label_view_name_penalty_player_3_left")
    self.label_view_name_penalty_player_1_right = builder.get_object("label_view_name_penalty_player_1_right")
    self.label_view_name_penalty_player_2_right = builder.get_object("label_view_name_penalty_player_2_right")
    self.label_view_name_penalty_player_3_right = builder.get_object("label_view_name_penalty_player_3_right")
    #
    self.button_blue_starts_left = builder.get_object("button_blue_starts_left")
    self.button_blue_starts_right = builder.get_object("button_blue_starts_right")
    self.button_type_view_invertedcontrolview = builder.get_object("button_type_view_invertedcontrolview")
    self.button_type_view_copycontrolview = builder.get_object("button_type_view_copycontrolview")
    self.button_separate_game_view_off = builder.get_object("button_separate_game_view_off")
    self.button_separate_game_view_on = builder.get_object("button_separate_game_view_on")
    self.button_log_functionality_off = builder.get_object("button_log_functionality_off")
    self.button_log_functionality_on = builder.get_object("button_log_functionality_on")
    self.entry_log_filename = builder.get_object("entry_log_filename")
    self.button_nostop_watch = builder.get_object("button_nostop_watch")
    self.button_stop_watch = builder.get_object("button_stop_watch")
    self.button_activate_timepenalty_player_1_left = builder.get_object("button_activate_timepenalty_player_1_left")
    self.button_activate_timepenalty_player_2_left = builder.get_object("button_activate_timepenalty_player_2_left")
    self.button_activate_timepenalty_player_3_left = builder.get_object("button_activate_timepenalty_player_3_left")
    self.button_activate_timepenalty_player_1_right = builder.get_object(
        "button_activate_timepenalty_player_1_right")
    self.button_activate_timepenalty_player_2_right = builder.get_object(
        "button_activate_timepenalty_player_2_right")
    self.button_activate_timepenalty_player_3_right = builder.get_object(
        "button_activate_timepenalty_player_3_right")
    self.button_clear_timepenalty_player_1_left = builder.get_object("button_clear_timepenalty_player_1_left")
    self.button_clear_timepenalty_player_2_left = builder.get_object("button_clear_timepenalty_player_2_left")
    self.button_clear_timepenalty_player_3_left = builder.get_object("button_clear_timepenalty_player_3_left")
    self.button_clear_timepenalty_player_1_right = builder.get_object("button_clear_timepenalty_player_1_right")
    self.button_clear_timepenalty_player_2_right = builder.get_object("button_clear_timepenalty_player_2_right")
    self.button_clear_timepenalty_player_3_right = builder.get_object("button_clear_timepenalty_player_3_right")
    self.button_stop_special_time_sequence = builder.get_object("button_stop_special_time_sequence")
    self.button_start_special_time_sequence = builder.get_object("button_start_special_time_sequence")
    self.button_clearreset_special_time_sequence = builder.get_object("button_clearreset_special_time_sequence")
    self.button_special_time_sequence_none = builder.get_object("button_special_time_sequence_none")
    self.button_special_time_sequence_timeout = builder.get_object("button_special_time_sequence_timeout")
    self.button_special_time_sequence_break = builder.get_object("button_special_time_sequence_break")
    self.button_special_time_sequence_penalty = builder.get_object("button_special_time_sequence_penalty")
    #
    self.ChooserButton_read_file_settings = builder.get_object("ChooserButton_read_file_settings")
    #
    self.label_log_dialog_time = builder.get_object("label_log_dialog_time")
    self.entry_log_dialog_remark_referee = builder.get_object("entry_log_dialog_remark_referee")
    self.entry_log_dialog_remark_scripter = builder.get_object("entry_log_dialog_remark_scripter")
    ##################################
    #   INIT the matrix of all inputs
    #
    col = 14
    row = 10
    logdata_array = [[""] * col for _ in range(row)]
    #neutralarrayline = ["","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]
    #logdata_array = []
    #for i in range(9):
    #    logdata_array.append(neutralarrayline)

    self.entry_logarray = []
    for i in range(10):
        self.entry_logarray.append([])
        for j in range(14):
            self.entry_logarray[i].append([])
            stringglade = str('%(prefix)s%(line)02d_%(column)02d'%{'prefix': "ld", 'line': i, 'column': j})
            #print(stringglade)
            #"ld"+str(i)+"_"+str(j)
            self.entry_logarray[i][j] = builder.get_object(stringglade)

    ##################################
    #self.entry_log_dialog_remark_equipment = builder.get_object("entry_log_dialog_remark_equipment")
    self.entry_anytime_line1intolog = builder.get_object("entry_anytime_line1intolog")
    self.entry_anytime_line2intolog = builder.get_object("entry_anytime_line2intolog")

    self.eventbox_exitbutton = builder.get_object("eventbox_exitbutton")
    self.eventbox_resetbutton = builder.get_object("eventbox_resetbutton")

    self.button_exit_view_window = builder.get_object("button_exit_view_window")
    #
    # connect all signals to actions
    builder.connect_signals(self)
    thread_time_control.connect("update_timers", self.update_timer_labels)
    #
    #        GDK_Escape = 0xff1b
    buffer_time_start_special_time_sequence = datetime.now()
    #
    # datetime data useful for elapsed time calculation and later for log / protocol
    start_time_of_the_game = datetime.now()
    start_time_control_timepenalty_player1_left = datetime.now()
    start_time_control_timepenalty_player2_left = datetime.now()
    start_time_control_timepenalty_player3_left = datetime.now()
    start_time_control_timepenalty_player1_right = datetime.now()
    start_time_control_timepenalty_player2_right = datetime.now()
    start_time_control_timepenalty_player3_right = datetime.now()
    start_time_of_second_period = datetime.now()
    end_time_of_the_game = datetime.now()  # usefull for log / protocol
    # for running time calculation of the main time counting
    buffer_last_time_stop = datetime.now()
    buffer_last_time_stop_control_timepenalty_player1_left = datetime.now()
    buffer_last_time_stop_control_timepenalty_player2_left = datetime.now()
    buffer_last_time_stop_control_timepenalty_player3_left = datetime.now()
    buffer_last_time_stop_control_timepenalty_player1_right = datetime.now()
    buffer_last_time_stop_control_timepenalty_player2_right = datetime.now()
    buffer_last_time_stop_control_timepenalty_player3_right = datetime.now()
    buffer_last_time_start = datetime.now()
    buffer_last_time_start_control_timepenalty_player1_left = datetime.now()
    buffer_last_time_start_control_timepenalty_player2_left = datetime.now()
    buffer_last_time_start_control_timepenalty_player3_left = datetime.now()
    buffer_last_time_start_control_timepenalty_player1_right = datetime.now()
    buffer_last_time_start_control_timepenalty_player2_right = datetime.now()
    buffer_last_time_start_control_timepenalty_player3_right = datetime.now()
    #
    # SEVERAL global parameters and stopwatches to be defined
    #       FIRST for period time downcounting
    #       SECOND for special_time_sequence
    #       3 for the time penalty players left
    #       3 for the time penalty players right
    #
    ellapsed_period_time_seconds = 0
    buffer_last_started_ellapsed_period_time_seconds = 0
    period_time_in_second = 15 * 60
    period_time_in_second_orig = 15*60
    counter_seconds_board = 15 * 60
    warning_timepenalty = warning_default_timepenalty
    warning_break_timeout = warning_default_break_timeout
    #
    # diverse parameter of special_time_sequence
    timepenalty_maximum_seconds = 120
    penalty_maximum_seconds = 45
    timeout_maximum_seconds = 1 * 60
    break_maximum_seconds = 300
    ellapsed_special_time_sequence_seconds = 0
    counter_seconds_special_time_sequence = 0
    ellapsed_maximum_time_special_sequence_seconds = 300
    #
    ellapsed_time_penalty_player_1_left_seconds = 0
    buffer_last_started_ellapsed_time_penalty_player_1_left_seconds = 0
    counter_seconds_time_penalty_player_1_left = 0
    #
    ellapsed_time_penalty_player_2_left_seconds = 0
    buffer_last_started_ellapsed_time_penalty_player_2_left_seconds = 0
    counter_seconds_time_penalty_player_2_left = 0
    #
    ellapsed_time_penalty_player_3_left_seconds = 0
    buffer_last_started_ellapsed_time_penalty_player_3_left_seconds = 0
    counter_seconds_time_penalty_player_3_left = 0
    #
    ellapsed_time_penalty_player_1_right_seconds = 0
    buffer_last_started_ellapsed_time_penalty_player_1_right_seconds = 0
    counter_seconds_time_penalty_player_1_right = 0
    #
    ellapsed_time_penalty_player_2_right_seconds = 0
    buffer_last_started_ellapsed_time_penalty_player_2_right_seconds = 0
    counter_seconds_time_penalty_player_2_right = 0
    #
    ellapsed_time_penalty_player_3_right_seconds = 0
    buffer_last_started_ellapsed_time_penalty_player_3_right_seconds = 0
    counter_seconds_time_penalty_player_3_right = 0
    #
    activated_time_penalty_player_1_left_to_enter_or_delete = False
    activated_time_penalty_player_2_left_to_enter_or_delete = False
    activated_time_penalty_player_3_left_to_enter_or_delete = False
    activated_time_penalty_player_1_right_to_enter_or_delete = False
    activated_time_penalty_player_2_right_to_enter_or_delete = False
    activated_time_penalty_player_3_right_to_enter_or_delete = False
    #
    time_penalty_player_1_left_initialized = False
    time_penalty_player_1_right_initialized = False
    time_penalty_player_2_left_initialized = False
    time_penalty_player_2_right_initialized = False
    time_penalty_player_3_left_initialized = False
    time_penalty_player_3_right_initialized = False
    #
    # diverse helpfull match status or timing
    game_started = False
    action_start_time_of_the_game_is_ACTIVE = False  # toggle button start / stop of the overall timing
    running_period_time = False
    running_first_period_time = False
    running_second_period_time = False
    running_penalty = False
    running_timeout = False
    running_break = False
    stopped_special_time_sequence = False
    # basic setup of team name
    left_team_is_blue = True  # at application start
    #
    running_time_penalty_player_1_left = False
    running_time_penalty_player_2_left = False
    running_time_penalty_player_3_left = False
    running_time_penalty_player_1_right = False
    running_time_penalty_player_2_right = False
    running_time_penalty_player_3_right = False
    #
    # buffer for switching the results from right to left in the score viewer
    buffer_counter_minutes_time_penalty_player_1 = 0
    buffer_counter_seconds_time_penalty_player_1 = 0
    buffer_counter_minutes_time_penalty_player_2 = 0
    buffer_counter_seconds_time_penalty_player_2 = 0
    buffer_counter_minutes_time_penalty_player_3 = 0
    buffer_counter_seconds_time_penalty_player_3 = 0
    buffer_running_time_penalty_player_1_left = False
    buffer_running_time_penalty_player_2_left = False
    buffer_running_time_penalty_player_3_left = False
    buffer_points_team = 0
    ################################
    # right is white background (and black letter)
    self.eventbox_control_right.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(1, 1, 1, 1))
    self.eventbox_view_team_color_right.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(1, 1, 1, 1))
    # right point area white
    self.eventbox_control_points_team_right.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(1, 1, 1, 1))
    self.eventbox_view_points_team_right.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(1, 1, 1, 1))
    self.eventbox_control_team_name_right.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(1, 1, 1, 1))
    self.eventbox_view_team_name_right.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(1, 1, 1, 1))
    # right letters of points black in white team
    self.label_control_points_team_right.override_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1))
    self.label_view_points_team_right.override_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1))
    self.label_control_team_name_right.override_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1))
    self.label_view_team_name_right.override_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 0, 1))
    #
    # left point area blue
    self.eventbox_control_left.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 1, 1))
    self.eventbox_view_team_color_left.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 1, 1))
    self.eventbox_control_points_team_left.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 1, 1))
    self.eventbox_view_points_team_left.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 1, 1))
    # left letters of points white in blue team
    self.label_control_points_team_left.override_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(1, 1, 1, 1))
    self.label_view_points_team_left.override_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(1, 1, 1, 1))

    self.eventbox_control_team_name_left.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 1, 1))
    self.eventbox_view_team_name_left.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(0, 0, 1, 1))
    self.label_control_team_name_left.override_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(1, 1, 1, 1))
    self.label_view_team_name_left.override_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(1, 1, 1, 1))
    #
    #
    self.entry_tournament_name.set_text("tournament")
    self.label_control_tournament_name.set_text("tournament")
    self.label_view_tournament_name.set_text("tournament")
    #
    self.entry_tournament_contact.set_text("Ms./Mr.")
    self.label_control_tournament_contact.set_text("Ms./Mr.")
    self.label_view_tournament_contact.set_text("Ms./Mr.")
    #
    self.entry_team_blue_name.set_text("TeamBLUE")
    self.label_control_team_name_left.set_text("TeamBLUE")
    self.label_view_team_name_left.set_text("Team BLUE")
    #
    self.entry_team_white_name.set_text("TeamWHITE")
    self.label_control_team_name_right.set_text("TeamWHITE")
    self.label_view_team_name_right.set_text("Team WHITE")
    #
    # make exit button for red
    self.eventbox_exitbutton.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(1, 0, 0, 1))
    #
    # orange https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11_color_names test rgb  100%  65%  0%
    self.eventbox_resetbutton.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(1, 0.65, 0, 1))
    # make reset button for red
    # self.eventbox_resetbutton.override_background_color(gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, gdk.RGBA(1, 0, 0, 1))
    self.label_control_special_time_sequence.set_text("none")
    #
    style_provider = gtk.CssProvider()
    ############################################################################################
    ############################################################################################
    #
    # modify that link below at a new installation
    #
    ############################################################################################
    css = open('/home/family/glade/scoreboard_uwr/scoreboard_gui_styles.css',
               'rb')  # rb needed for python 3 support
    ############################################################################################
    ############################################################################################
    css_data = css.read()
    css.close()
    style_provider.load_from_data(css_data)
    gtk.StyleContext.add_provider_for_screen(gdk.Screen.get_default(), style_provider,
                                             gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    GUI = GUIclass()
    GUI.controlwindow.show()
    gtk.main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the links. I will take a look at it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297886/putting-glade-interface-in-python   this one show to you how to structure a code and make it working (a bit shorter than my previous indications)